# mod_rewrite redirect directory to parent directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Recently I moved my site to Amazon EC2 instance. I want to redirect requests for

```
http://www.domain.com/data/
to
http://www.domain.com
```

so any previous paths in the old website like

`http://www.domain.com/data/kjk/sds/sds/index.html` should become `http://www.domain.com/kjk/sds/sds/index.html`

I have tried a couple of mod_rewrite rules using htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^data/. / [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?
(not tested!)

```
RewriteRule ^data/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: On my server it works. Did you enable .htaccess? Is the .htaccess in the root directory /? And there is no directory/file like /kjk/sds/sds/index.html?

Comment: yes htaccess is in the root directory, no there is no physical file like /kjk/sds/sds/ it think its handled by permealinks, bascially i am using wordpress and on my old install wordpress was installed in http://www.domain.com/data/, now its http://www.domain.com , so now i want anyone who access using domain.com/data/ to still work as usual..

Comment: Put `RewriteRule ^data/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]` direct under RewriteBase /